# Managed to delete Event_Calendar_Status and cannot reinstate

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, datetime

When trying to get rid of notification emails every time I create a calendar event, I have managed to delete the ?built-in? event calendar status term. I have tried to reinstate it but machine will not allow the same name as original. It's causing an undefined index Notice which will not now let me save any new events.

Have not got much stuff on the site yet, so may have to disable, uninstall and reinstall the calendar module?

This appears when creating new calendar event:
Notice: Undefined index: event_calendar_status in event_calendar_form_alter() (line 293 of web1/user47631/website/sites/all/modules/ event_calendar/event_calendar.module)

Grateful for any help or suggestions...

Cynthia

Comment: See [event_calendar_status unavailable after un- and re-install](https://drupal.org/node/2284631)

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the module, but here are few things I can suggest take a database backup before you take any step.Uninstalling calendar module should be not helpful, as it seems settings to be changed in event_calendar module.

How you deleted the status term,did you make any direct changes to database?can you revert back those changes? You can setup event_calendar module on fresh drupal installation to track what changes can be done to make it work.

Not sure, but keep uninstalling and reinstalling event_calendar module as last option.

I guess [event_calendar](https://drupal.org/project/event_calendar) provides UI for mailing notifications settings, as the project page says

> This module also gives an Admin UI to change status (approval/denied)
>   of events and a mailing system.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions! I deleted the Taxonomy term event_status by mistake - stupid of me! I thought I would be able to re-create it but it will not allow a machine name that has previously existed it seems. Creating a new similar Taxonomy term didn;t work either as it is still looking for something that I cannot now add. I'm about to uninstall the calendar and try again. Thanks a lot for your help